# XSLT: How do I inject a document, then apply tempates to it?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to combine and process several files using XSLT. Here's an example of the type of structure I'm working with:

page.html

```
<html>
    <head/>
</html>
```

head.html

```
<head>
    <title />
</head>
```

proc.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/html/head">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('head.html')/head" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/head/title">
    <title>this is a contrived example</title>
</xsl>
```

I'm applying `proc.xsl` against `page.html`. Everything works, but note that the match in the second template element has to be relative to the included document rather than the one that's including it. Is that wise? Is there a way to ensure the `apply-templates` instruction works in the context of the including document, rather than the included one?

To clarify, the result I am looking for is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>this is a contrived example</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

I also tried include/import with an xsl file like this:

head.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/html/head">
    <head>
        <title />
    </head>
</xsl:template>
```

Again, this injects the head markup fine, but fails to process the `title` element.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The match in the second template (or in any template) is not "relative to the included document" (or any document). And the `apply-templates` instruction works in the context in which it is called; in your example, in the context of `/html/head` of the `page.html` document - because that is the context established by the parent template. What is the actual problem here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure that terminology is way off. What I mean is that the xpath expression in the match has to begin with `/head` rather than `/html` i.e. it matches against the document that is loaded, rather than the result of applying the first template to the initial document. I'll update with an example of the result I'm after.

Comment: You can just change the template match to `match="head/title"` or just `match="title"` as then it won't matter if `head` is the root element or not.

Comment: @TimC This is essentially what I have, but I'm concerned that such matches are too generic and might end up matching a title in an unwanted context. However, with everything else I have going on in this process, I think that might be the best approach.

Comment: If you want your "head/title" template to only match the second document, perhaps you could make use of a "mode" attribute?

Comment: @BobbyJack "*might end up matching a title in an unwanted context.*" This cannot happen if you use `xsl:apply-templates` to define the context.

Comment: I also think your solution ist god, only add a mode (as Tim C said)

Answer (score 0):

You never place document('head.html')/head element into the current document (or any document where it is not root element), so it's kind of strange to expect it will be interpreted as /html/head.

Now, you can probably copy this element into some other document and then apply templates on it if you really want that behavior.

```
<xsl:variable name="head">
    <html>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('head.html')/head" />
    </html>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($head)/html/head"/>
```

perhaps?

Comment: Can you explain "You never place document('head.html')/head element"...? I thought what I was doing did exactly that. I know this might not be 'the xslt way', but I would have thought that combining several documents would be a common-enough use case that this would be supported, somehow.

Comment: document() function does not include another document processed document, it merely parses it as a separate node-set. I don't think it can add anything to the document being processed, it's immutable. parsed document (node-set) is not included anywhere and is not in any way related to any other document (input or output)